# Maven: Inheriting resources of dependency

Tags: maven

I got a project that have a dependency to another one. In the second one, there are some resources. From the first one, I'm doing the following:

```
ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(filename);
```

It's failing to get the resource from the dependency. Any idea why this can happen?

Thanks,
Mooncrosser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to load a file that's on the classpath you probably mean `getResourceAsStream`.

The other possibility is that when you're running it you're not running it with the full classpath.